# CSS: two identical elements display differently on 2 different websites

Tags: css, padding

On a [development site](http://dev.sec-2-sec.com), I have some social widgets set up correctly.

I can't replicate this on the [production site](http://sec-2-sec.com), even though I'm sure I'm using the same CSS.

[image]

The padding-bottom on `li.twitter-balloon` is overlapping with the padding-top of `li.linkedin-balloon`.  Why is this occurring on the production site and not on the development site?  Thanks.

Comment: Here's a diff on the relevant CSS: http://www.diffchecker.com/6xpnpxaq
Clearly there are a few differences.

Comment: I voted down since the question is misleading (the code is not the same), not informative and unlikely to help others. @Steve - you better delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the CSS you are using are not exactly the same.

On your production site, in line 294 (or another line number with the same content) of your style.css file, you have `margin-bottom:-10px;`, which is the reason why they are different. If you delete this line, they will look the same.

Comment: You nailed it.  Thanks Conny.

Answer (score 0):

On dev server your css is

```
.twitter-balloon {
    background: url("images/twitter-balloon.png") no-repeat scroll right 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top: 1px dotted #D8D8D8;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

on live its :

```
.twitter-balloon {
    background: url("images/twitter-balloon.png") no-repeat scroll right 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top: 1px dotted #D8D8D8;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

just remove margin here